# Why does the line of the pdf jump to the wrong one of its tex file and vice versa sometimes?

Tags: sublime-text

I am using LaTeX with LaTeXTools on Sublime Text 4. It sometimes happens that when double-clicked, the line of the pdf jumps to the wrong line of its tex file, and when the tex compiled, the line of the tex file the cursor's focusing on jumps to the wrong location of its pdf.

Anyone knows why it happens and how to fix this tricky issue?

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/SyncTeX_Errors